# How to Client Side and Server Side integration of IBM TeaLeaf

Tags: tealeaf

I have to implement TeaLeaf analytics for our application so i am doing sample POc for android and iphone environment for hybrids application. Anyone please advice me how can i implement the TeaLeaf stuff in my POC.

Below that activity i did,

1. create sample app version project and add android/iphone environment
2. application-descriptor.xml i added IBM teaLeaf SDK 
   what else i have do? i was searching google and following ibm knowledge center also there is not much clarity for tutorial and how can i test in development environment.

below that link i referred :
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.integ.doc/integ/t_tealeaf_client.html

Comment: You need to contact Tealeaf support/website and refer its API reference and  usage.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems like you're attempting to create a connection between IBM MobileFirst Platform 6.3.0 and IBM Tealeaf. I work on integrations of IBM Tealeaf On-Cloud with client e-commerce platforms and it seems like you might be dealing with IBM Tealeaf On-Premise.

That being said, my understanding of the process for the On-Cloud implementation is that there are a few libraries you need to make sure are being included on pages you'd like Tealeaf to observe:

- Tealeaf.js (distributed by IBM)
- Sizzle.js
- JQuery, if the page uses it ... also note that if the site uses JQuery, you need to provision from IBM the JQuery flavor of Tealeaf.js instead of the W3C flavor.
- Hammer.js
- Pako.js (again this assumes the On-Cloud version of Tealeaf, as this is a library for compressing data a being sent to IBM cloud-service collectors. In the On-Premise version my understanding is that this data is written to a file that is saved to the local hardware.)

How the libraries are included is something you'd decide when working with the client's server and development team - every organization has their preferences. Generally though they'd be inserted on pages that need to be monitored and the Tealeaf.js config would be edited to specify the endpoint of the collector for the regional data center on which space was provisioned for the client (in the US, either in Dallas or Washington DC.)

As for the On-Premise implementation of Tealeaf, you can jump in to the documentation here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2MBL/tealeaf_product_family_welcome.html